Embedding between dual spaces induced by embedding between spaces
I am reading a notes and the author didn't explicitly write out the induced embedding. I didn't see what the definition of such an embedding shall be.. Thanks for help.
Here are his words. Since, by Sobolev embedding, $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ is continuously embedded in $L^{p*}(\Omega)$, we have by duality that $(L^{p*}(\Omega))'$ is continuously embedded in $(W^{1,p'}_0(\Omega))'$. And he continues with that, the Sobolev embedding exponent is $p^*=\frac{Np}{N-p}$, and if we define $p_*=(p^*)'=\frac{Np}{Np-N+p}$, then we have $L^{p_*}\subseteq (W^{1,p'}_0(\Omega))'.$
I don't know how to define the induced embedding and how to derive the embedding that $L^{p_*}\subseteq (W^{1,p'}_0(\Omega))'...$ Any help will be appreciated.

the embedding of the dual spaces == adjoint/dual operator of the embedding operator.
